# How to log in with a non-root account on MySQL Command Line Client?

Tags: mysql

Everytime I open the command line client, I am asked to log in with the root account by providing the root account password. So my question is, is there a way to log in with another account on the client and how?

Thanks!

Comment: mysql -u {username} -p
Here you can read about options - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html

Comment: @AntonM. I have tried this before. After I typed this command and pressed Enter, the command does not run, instead, the promp jumped to another line (waiting me to end the command with a semicolon probably).

Answer (score 0):

Use the -u flag. It should promot you for that users password

mysql -u someotherusername

Comment: I have tried this before. After I typed this command and pressed Enter, the command does not run, instead, the promp jumped to another line (waiting me to end the command with a semicolon probably).